# Functional derivative or Euler-Lagrange?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

What is the difference between the functional derivative and the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Answer (score 5):

Briefly, the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
$$ \frac{\delta S}{\delta q(t)}~=~0$$
states that the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) of the action $S[q]$ vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

The equations which involve an integral are called  functional and for extremum of functional, Euler Lagrange equations are used. For example the functional could be $\int \sqrt{(1-(dy/dx)^2}dx$ which is the functional for a length of any curve y, using Euler Lagrange equations, we can show that the equation is a straight line which means the extremum for distance is a straight line.